# Converting a part of string to an integer in turbo c++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I want to find a way to convert the number in the string to an integer.
i am able to find numbers in the string using **isnum** function but the problem is **how to i make it an integer**.

Comment: Read [Why should I not use Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-should-i-not-use-turbo-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the `atoi` function.

Here is the code example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi):

```
/* atoi example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, fgets */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */

int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer[256];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  fgets (buffer, 256, stdin);
  i = atoi (buffer);
  printf ("The value entered is %d. Its double is %d.\n",i,i*2);
  return 0;
}
```